# True Type Font editing

Tags: fonts, truetype-fonts

I have a .ttf file in which I need to add some missing characters.
Maybe some of you have faced and overcame this earlier?
I would relay appreciate your time spared ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Fontforge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) to the rescue.